# R code to find slope in Tableau

Tags: r, tableau-api

I tried to write the formula to get the slope using R and Tableau integration.

My formula within the calculated field shows to be a valid one. However, when I try to plot the same, I get an error. The formula i am using is as follows:

SCRIPT_REAL("mydata <- data.frame(cbind(yy = .arg1, xx = .arg2)); fit <- lm(yy ~ xx,new data=mydata); fit$coeff[[2]]",(avg([Revenue Growth])),(avg([WTI]) ))

The error i receive is :
[image]

Any help with the same would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Take `cbind` out and put the variables straight into `data.frame`.  You might have confused the parser with unnecessary calls and dots..

Comment: Hi Richard, Tried doing as advised. It still gives error             SCRIPT_REAL("mydata <- data.frame ([Revenue Growth ]= .arg1, [WTI] = .arg2); 
fit <- lm([NAXI Revenue Growth] ~ [WTI] ),new data=mydata); 
fit$coeff[[2]]",(avg([Revenue Growth])),(avg([WTI]) ))

Comment: Tell the Tableau help desk to send me and all the rest of the frequent SO-R contributors a licensed copy of Tableau and I'm sure you will start getting answers on the weekends.

Comment: Replace `fit <- lm(yy ~ xx,new data=mydata);` with `fit <- lm(yy ~ xx,data=mydata);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SCRIPT_REAL(
'mydata<- data.frame(yy=.arg1, xx=.arg2);
fit <- lm(yy~xx,mydata)$coefficients[2]',
    AVG([Revenue Growth],
    AVG([WTI])
)
```